# How do I assign a /64 ipv6 subnet

Tags: networking, ipv6

So for my application I want to  be able to use any ipv6 address for communication but right now I can't even let curl use the addresses so I'm stuck.

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- netplan as network manager
- netcup vps as hosting service

`/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` chances were applied with `netplan apply`
I tried many things in this config but with no luck

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - x.x.x.x/22
            - xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64
            gateway4: x.x.x.x
            gateway6: xxxx::1
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - x.x.x.x
                - x.x.x.x
                - xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx
```

command I used for checking if an address was available

`curl -6 google.com --interface xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:0:0:0:5` with as response: `curl: (45) bind failed with errno 99: Cannot assign requested address`

I also tried using `ndppd` as recommended by friends who do have this working but this just timed out every ipv6 request.

I also tried messing around with `ip add` and `ip route` but also with no luck.